# Можно ли в Angular послать строку в директиву не используя кавычки?

Tags: angular2, angular

Нужно передать в *Input* параметр компонента строку, я нашел такой способ:

```
<my-component [stringInput]="'Ivan'"></my-component>
```

Как сделать тоже самое только не брать `Ivan` в кавычки `'`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Квадратные скобки нужно использовать только в случае если выражение нужно обработать в рантайме, если это строка - `stringInput="Ivan"` достаточно.

К тому же если не использовать квадратные скобки - то строка считается как константа. Если использовать квадратные скобки `[stringInput]="'Ivan'"` - Angular будет каждый раз проверять не изменилась ли данная строка.